# Losing the grey margin padding in a ggplot

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

A would like to plot geom_tile() without displaying the surrounding grey frame. Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(melt(volcano), aes(x = X1, y = X2, z = value,fill = value)) + geom_tile() 
print(p)
```

Produces the figure below, which would look better had not the theme background framed the heatmap proper. I imaging the padding is the same 4% as in base graphics. It's good to have it most of the time, but not always.

I assume the same solution to this problem could be applied to other geoms as well.
[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

just do `print(p1 + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)))` and that will get rid of the gray space around