# Adjusting graph bar height with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df2 <- iris[c(5,1)]
df3 <- aggregate(df2$Sepal.Length, list(df2$Species), mean)
names(df3) <- c("x","y")

ggplot(df3, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=x),stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

I have successfully removed axis tick marks and labels from this plot. I am trying to get rid of the blank grey space underneath the bars. Zero should be the lower bound for the chart. I've been searching unsuccessfully for an adjustment function to either pull the bars down or to cut off the bottom grey portion. The hope is that ggplots are not hardwired with the extra space underneath.

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768107/losing-the-grey-margin-padding-in-a-ggplot), the solution might work for you. (you probably just need `print(p + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following elements to your code (inspired by [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2)):

```
theme_classic()
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

Instead of `theme_classic()`, you can also use `theme_bw()` which will add horizontal and vertical lines to the plot.

You code should then look like this:

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=x),stat="identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to separate the left bat from the axis? I changed the ```scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))``` to ```scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.1,0))``` and it did work, but I am unsure whether this is the best way to proceed

Comment: @PabloHerrerosCantis You can also achieve by setting the `width`-parameter of `geom_bar` to a value lower than `0.9`.